# Select opening and closing balance from SQL Server table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, select

I need to select opening and closing balance from a database with these table

```
TransDate    Credit    Debit    Datasource
------------------------------------------
2014-01-01   5000      NULL     3
2014-01-07   NULL      2000     3
2014-01-11   5000      NULL     3
2014-02-03   5000      NULL     3
2014-02-06   NULL      5000     4
2014-02-11   5000      NULL     3
2014-02-21   NULL      5000     4
2014-02-28   5000      NULL     3
2014-03-01   5000      NULL     3
```

but it gave me this, [please see here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/a0366/6)

what am I doing wrong?

I expected too see

```
TransDate    Credit    Debit     Balance
------------------------------------------
2014-01-11   NULL      NULL      8000      <- opening balance     
2014-02-03   5000      NULL      
2014-02-06   NULL      5000      
2014-02-11   5000      NULL      
2014-02-21   NULL      5000      
2014-02-28   5000      NULL      13000     <- closing balance
```

My query was

```
Select 
    MAX(TransDate) TransDate, 0 Credit, 0 Debit, 
    SUM(ISNULL([Credit], 0) - ISNULL([Debit], 0)) AS Balance 
From 
    Transactions 
WHERE 
    DataSource = 4 OR DataSource = 3 
    AND TransDate < '2014/02/01'

UNION

Select 
    TransDate, Credit, Debit, 0 
From 
    Transactions 
WHERE 
    DataSource = 4 OR DataSource = 3 
    AND TransDate >= '2014/02/01' AND TransDate <= '2014/02/28'

UNION

Select 
    MIN(TransDate) TransDate, 0 Credit, 0 Debit, 
    SUM(ISNULL([Credit], 0) - ISNULL([Debit], 0)) AS Balance 
From 
    Transactions 
WHERE 
    DataSource = 4 OR DataSource = 3 
    AND TransDate >= '2014/02/01' AND TransDate <= '2014/02/28'
```

Comment: how did you come up with this opening balance of 8000 ?

Comment: the report is being run for febuary 2014, so i add all credit -  all debit. you can see two credit 5000 and one debit 2000 before febuary

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In SQL Server 2012+, you would use cumulative sums:

```
select sum(coalesce(credit, 0) - coalesce(debit, 0)) over (order by transdate) as balance
from table;
```

You could get the first and last balance using a variety of methods, such as:

```
with b as (
      select t.* sum(coalesce(credit, 0) - coalesce(debit, 0)) over (order by transdate) as balance
      from table t
     )
select *
from ((select top 1 b.*
       from b
       order by transdate
      ) union all
      (select top 1 b.*
       from b
       order by transdate desc
      )
     ) b
```

You can also get the balance as of any intermediate date as well.

Comment: thanks, but this does not work this in sql-server 2008, i get an error `Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
Incorrect syntax near 'order'.
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 8
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'union'.`